# Reversing first and last names using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to take this table and take the names, when I click one radio button it changes the names from something like: Tom Hanks to Hanks, Tom. Here is the html:

```
<h1>Address Book</h1>

Show Names as:
<input name="change_last_first" value="last" type="radio">First, Last
<input name="change_last_first" value="first" type="radio">Last, First
<div>
    <table <thead="">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </tbod
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>9001</td>
                <td class="name">Tom Hanks</td>
                <td>tomhanks@moviestars.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9002</td>
                <td class="name">Bruce Willis</td>
                <td>brucewillis@moviestars.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9003</td>
                <td class="name">Jim Carrey</td>
                <td>jimcarrey@moviestars.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9004</td>
                <td class="name">Tom Cruise</td>
                <td>tomcruise@moviestars.com</td>
            </tr>
            <script>

            </script>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Interview Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./webassets/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
    <h1>Company Staff List</h1>

<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>9001</td>
                <td>Tom Hanks</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9002</td>
                <td>Bruce Willis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9003</td>
                <td>Jim Carrey</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9004</td>
                <td>Tom Cruise</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery, its all I could come up with and does not work at all. :(

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='change_last_first']").click(function () {
        $(".name").text(function() {
            $(this).split(" ").reverse();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Updated the answer with 2 options. Check out the demos.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` the result. Also since you are using the function arg syntax of `text` use the second argument of the function for the current text.

```
    $(".name").text(function(_, cur) {
         return curText.split(/\s+|,/).reverse();
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSWpt/)**

Another easy way to handle this assuming the general format of name is `First Last` or `Last, First`:

```
 $("input[name='change_last_first']").change(function () {
        var arr = [" ", ","],
            sep = this.value === 'first' ? 0 : 1;
        $(".name").text(function (_, curText) {
            return curText.split(arr[sep % 2]).reverse().join(arr[(sep + 1) % 2]);
        });
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KBuPE/)**

Comment: I made a tiny requirement in how the names are changed from :

Tom Hanks to Hanks, Tom and backwards.

Comment: @thetao Thats what 2nd demo will give you.

Comment: @thetao This is the third option of permutation combination :)...  Try this link. http://jsfiddle.net/b5bj9/

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to `split` full name with space and than you can use `reverse()`.

**Note:** because `reverse()` is a method of array instances. It won't directly work on a string. You should first split the characters of the string into an array, reverse the array and then join back into a string.

```
$("input[name='change_last_first']").click(function () {
      $(".name").each(function() {            
          var revName = $(this).text().split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
          $(this).text(revName);
      });
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/KBuPE/2/)